# Establishing continuity of a multivariable function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

We have a compact set $X$ in $\mathbb R^n$ and $v$ is a real valued function defined on $X$ by $v(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\sum x_i$. Now is it true that $v$ is continuous?

I think so, but my analysis is somewhat rusty. My argument is as follows: let $\vec{z_i}=(x_{i_1},\dots,x_{i_n})$ be a sequence in $X$ such that $\vec{z_i}\to \vec{z}=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$. We wish to show that $v(\vec{z_i})\to v(\vec{z})$. But this is clearly true since $x_{i_k}\to x_k$ for each $k$ and so $\sum x_{i_k}\to \sum x_k$. Hence $v$ is continuous.

Can someone confirm this? I have nowhere used compactness. The question arises in the context of showing that in a transportation network a maximum flow exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument is correct. However to be sure of really understanding what means continuity of a function with several variables, you should ask yourself what is behind your argument *But this is clearly true since $x_{i_k}\to x_k$ for each $k$*, and why you can use sequential arguments to prove the continuity?

Comment: For point 1 I use the result that a sequence of vectors is convergent to a limit vector iff the sequence for each coordinate converges to the corresponding limit coordinate. For point 2 I use the fact that X is a metric space and so a function is continuous iff it is sequentially continuous. Is this correct? Is compactness not required?

Comment: That is correct and indeed compactness is not required.